# Displaying ExpandableListView child items in GridView

Tags: android, expandablelistview, android-adapter, android-gridview

I want to display a expandable list view with child items inside a grid view.
Is there any good tutorial for it?

I tried some tutorials and came to a point it displays child items that are given in grid adapter but i want to display the child items that are given in the main class and not as in the adapter class.

Can any one help me out?

Tutorial pages also enough for me?

Will upload my code later!
Please help me out!
Thanks!